# Is the nilradical of a Lie algebra functorial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ be Lie algebras over some commutative ring $K$ (I assume this works in general, but if not can restrict to the real case if necessary), and suppose that we have a homomorphism of Lie algebras $f: \mathfrak{h} \to \mathfrak{g}$. Does this restrict to a Lie algebra homomorphism $\operatorname{nil}(\mathfrak{h}) \to \operatorname{nil}(\mathfrak{g})$?

If not, what if we include the hypothesis that $f$ is an injection?

Comment: Well ... Let $\mathfrak g$ be any Lie algebra with trivial nilradical, and for any nonzero $x \in \mathfrak g$, let $\mathfrak h :=K \cdot x = nil(\mathfrak h) \subset \mathfrak g$ ....

Comment: Even more generally, if we take $\mathrm{nil}(\mathfrak{g})\leq\mathfrak{h} \leq \mathfrak{g}$. Then $\mathrm{nil}(\mathfrak{g})\leq\mathrm{nil}(\mathfrak{h})$. So this can fail even for reasonable (e.g. nonabelian) subalgebras with the inclusion map.

Comment: If anything, one should ask this question for the case that $\mathfrak h$ is an *ideal* of $\mathfrak g$. If one thinks "functorially", ideals are more reasonable "subobjects" of Lie algebras than just any subalgebra. (Just like normal subgroups are the "right" subobject of groups.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg but thinking functorially makes the assumption "the image is an ideal" clumsy. It's not even closed under composition.